# Stop moving page title in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, webpage

Some websites I'm using always make the web title move or blink when, for example, a new mail has just arrived. It is really disturbing as it's not an emergency and usually I'm busy browsing other pages.

I can't stand it any longer, but I have to use those services. I want to stop this kind of behavior either by installing a new extension or writing a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script. But I can't find one and have no idea about how to detect and stop the JavaScript code. What is the solution?

Comment: What sites do this? Without looking at how they do it, it's unlikely anyone can stop it.

Comment: I met this on mail.163.com and web.qq.com, both are in Chinese and require login. It may be done with changiung `document.title` in `setTimeout`. But I don't think I can get the id the `setTimeout`(s) returns.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't default behaviour of Firefox. There must be another application or Firefox plugin causing it. If it only happens when you get new mail, then maybe your email client is causing it.

Comment: The **webpage** is causing it, and I want to stop it.